# Regression analysis with binary independent variables

Tags: multiple-regression, binary-data

Should one use regression analysis when all independent variables are binary categorical (0,1) to see their effect on continuous dependent? Some suggest that regression shouldn't be used in this case.

Comment: A regression when all independent variables are binary is also called an "ANOVA". It is OK to use a regression analysis in this case.

Comment: Who suggested it and what was their reasoning? It might be more illuminating if we could explain where the issue lies; it's fine to use regression, but maybe there's something interesting to cover in why they think there's a problem.

Comment: A researcher maintains that a mix of qulitative (binary) & quantitative independent variables should be used in Multiple regression. If all predictor variables are categorical, one should use analytical design and statistical technique more precise--